# Angular setDirty to a page without form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page with some jquery UI sliders on them. When the user interacts with it, I want to use the setDirty api of angular so that I can warn the user when he tries to leave the page about unsaved changes. However I'm not using any form inputs for this.

Where should I call the setDirty() method in my slider directive / controller?

Comment: You should call it in the directive where you created the jquery UI sliders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used it like `ng-form="myForm"` to the parent div enclosing the sliders so that it'd inherit the setPristine/setDirty behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a form, which creates $scope variable of the same name as the form name. Access this $scope variable and set it to dirty in change event of the slider.